# Geom_line are not following geom_bar and geom_dot after new geom_bar rank

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a ggplot2 plot that is not working the way i want to..:)
The first plot is showing the orginal plot. Bars illustrate each participants at different timepoints(online/offline).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6RhC.png)

Next plot i have reorder/ or ranked the bars displaying lowest score first. As you can see, the lines is following the old structure and not following the ranked bars.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QooOz.png)

the code for the ranking and plot:

```
delta.plot.indiv1 = delta.plot.indiv %>% 
  group_by(Learning) %>% 
  mutate(position = rank(+tot))


ggplot(delta.plot.indiv1,
       aes(x=Learning, y=tot, color=sub,group=sub))+
labs(title = "Distribution of online and offline learning", x = "", y = "Time(S/trial)")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("online"="Online", "offline"="Offline"))+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, size=.5)+
   scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(aes(group=position),alpha=0.1, stat = "identity", position="dodge")+
   geom_line(aes(group=sub),position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = position), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, family = "serif",face="bold", colour="black", size = 12), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(family = "serif",face="bold", colour="black", size = 12),
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0.5, family = "serif", face="bold", colour="black", size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(family = "serif", face="bold", size = 10),
        legend.text = element_text(color = "black", family = "serif", size=10, face="bold"))+
  facet_grid(.~age.group)+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

If dataset is needed I can provide that?

Dataset:

```
dput(delta.plot.indiv1)
structure(list(sub = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 
61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
64L), levels = c("", "01TIPP", "02TIPP", "03TIPP", "04TIPP", 
"05TIPP", "06TIPP", "07TIPP", "08TIPP", "09TIPP", "10TIPP", "11TIPP", 
"12TIPP", "13TIPP", "14TIPP", "15TIPP", "16TIPP", "17TIPP", "18TIPP", 
"19TIPP", "20TIPP", "21TIPP", "22TIPP", "23TIPP", "24TIPP", "25TIPP", 
"26TIPP", "27TIPP", "28TIPP", "29TIPP", "30TIPP", "31TIPP", "32TIPP", 
"33TIPP", "34TIPP", "35TIPP", "41TIPP", "42TIPP", "43TIPP", "44TIPP", 
"45TIPP", "46TIPP", "47TIPP", "48TIPP", "49TIPP", "50TIPP", "51TIPP", 
"52TIPP", "53TIPP", "54TIPP", "55TIPP", "56TIPP", "57TIPP", "58TIPP", 
"59TIPP", "60TIPP", "61TIPP", "62TIPP", "63TIPP", "64TIPP", "65TIPP", 
"66TIPP", "68TIPP", "69TIPP"), class = "factor"), age.group = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("senior", 
"u13"), class = "factor"), Learning = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("online", 
"offline", "total"), class = "factor"), tot = c(0.243, -0.2007, 
0.442399943, 0.1558, -0.0805, 0.3858, 0.183, 0.3005, 0.394, -0.0333, 
0.0831, 0.4231, 0.6312, 0.1811, 0.2035, 0.3559, 0.2471, 0.253, 
0.0859, 0.237, 0.0104, 0.391, 0.3872, 0, 0.386549962, 0.2772, 
0.2211, 0.0215999999999998, 0.0934999999999999, 0.5438, 0.2204, 
0.116449988, 0.123199975, 0.3537, 0.4956, 0.2818, 0.3722, 0.1575, 
0.467, 0.4341, 0.3663, 0.2735, 0.2831, 0.0981000000000001, 0.1648, 
0.3649, 0.242, 0.3213, 0.4375, 0.3231, 0.6152, 0.2207, -0.0631999999999999, 
0.125749994, 0.295400035, 0.336000013, 0.391049958, 0.420749986, 
0.209400022, 0.567149961, 0.588150025, 0.218700003, 0.100900018, 
0.2087, 0.187, -0.148150003, 0.1305, 0.4307, -0.1377, 0.0793999999999999, 
0.0974999999999999, -0.15799998, 0.3869, 0.5595, 0.0750000000000002, 
-0.345, 0.063799961, -0.013450019, -0.00435001900000009, -0.228900042, 
-0.0807000059999998, 0.146399988, 0.063300012, 0.0834499730000001, 
0.169649993, -0.12499993, 0.221549998, -0.211399925, 0.155400028, 
0.0641499620000001, 0.135849957, 0.271399994, -0.105500009, -0.0452500039999999, 
0.289299953, 0.116900051, 0.144499989, -0.172299992, 0.0716000299999999, 
-0.115149914, -0.170499966, -0.2222, -0.1189, -0.0132000000000001, 
-0.1756, -0.1147, -0.2183, 0.0641, -0.1536, 0.00309999999999988, 
-0.1162, -0.1341, 0.0628, -0.2751, 0.0910000480000002, 0.00639999999999996, 
0.217150056, -0.266399956, -0.100300014, -0.179900015, -0.0598499539999999, 
-0.128449976, -0.275499976, -0.282550013, 0.17720002, -0.0894499659999999
), position = c(29, 1, 56, 16, 2, 46, 20, 37, 51, 4, 8, 53, 63, 
19, 21, 42, 30, 31, 9, 27, 6, 49, 48, 5, 47, 33, 26, 7, 10, 59, 
24, 13, 14, 41, 58, 34, 45, 17, 57, 54, 44, 32, 35, 11, 18, 43, 
28, 38, 55, 39, 62, 25, 3, 15, 36, 40, 50, 52, 22, 60, 61, 23, 
12, 56, 55, 16, 48, 62, 17, 43, 46, 14, 61, 63, 42, 1, 38, 31, 
33, 6, 28, 51, 37, 44, 53, 20, 58, 9, 52, 40, 49, 59, 25, 30, 
60, 47, 50, 12, 41, 23, 13, 7, 21, 32, 11, 24, 8, 39, 15, 34, 
22, 18, 36, 4, 45, 35, 57, 5, 26, 10, 29, 19, 3, 2, 54, 27)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -126L), groups = structure(list(
    Learning = structure(1:2, levels = c("online", "offline", 
    "total"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:63, 
        64:126), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Best A

Expect that lines can be connected to the dots

Comment: Welcome to SO! From your images and your code I would guess that you messed up the grouping, i.e. you are mapping different variables on the `group` aes. And guessing further I would guess that simply doing `group=position` in `geom_line` will not fix that issue but you could give it a try. For more help it would indeed help if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data shared via `dput()`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I will provide the data in the Question above :) I have tried with group=position in geom_line but it result in lines at random placed.

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in my comment your issue could not be fixed by the `group` aes. The reason is that on the one hand we want to dodge the lines by `position` as for the points and the bars but at the same time we want to group by `sub` to connect by subject.

Instead we have to manually dodge the lines, i.e. we have to manually compute the x positions for the lines. Basically this could be achieved using the formula:

```
mutate(position_line = as.numeric(factor(Learning)) + dodge_width * (position - n / 2) / n)
```

where `n` is the number of subjects per `age.group`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

dodge_width <- .9
pd <- position_dodge(width = dodge_width)
delta.plot.indiv1 <- delta.plot.indiv |> 
  group_by(age.group, Learning) |> 
  mutate(position = rank(+tot), n = n()) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  mutate(position_line = as.numeric(factor(Learning)) + dodge_width * (position - n / 2) / n)

ggplot(
  delta.plot.indiv1,
  aes(x = Learning, y = tot, color = sub, group = position)
) +
  labs(title = "Distribution of online and offline learning", x = "", y = "Time(S/trial)") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("online" = "Online", "offline" = "Offline")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = .5) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(alpha = 0.1, stat = "identity", position = pd) +
  geom_line(aes(x = position_line, group = sub)) +
  geom_point(position = pd) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, family = "serif", face = "bold", colour = "black", size = 12),
    axis.text.x = element_text(family = "serif", face = "bold", colour = "black", size = 12),
    axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, family = "serif", face = "bold", colour = "black", size = 12),
    legend.title = element_text(family = "serif", face = "bold", size = 10),
    legend.text = element_text(color = "black", family = "serif", size = 10, face = "bold")
  ) +
  facet_grid(. ~ age.group) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Wauw, thank you so much @stefan. That solved the problem and make sense in order to do it manual ! Very grateful:))